Hard crash with Quicktime on simple edits, no help from Apple
I use Quicktime player as a direct and simple way to trim the head and foot of videos I record in ecamm.
I'm on a Mac Studio with Apple silicon and plenty of ram and hd space. Sonoma 14.5 and Quicktime is 10.5, the latest version.
Sometimes once a week, sometimes three times a day, QT freezes completely on the split clip command and even the power button won't restart. I have to unplug and restart from there.
Console shows no reports.
I know QT has been problematic for years here and there, and Apple support was zero help. Any suggestions on what I might try? Thanks.
I tried to edit videos, I expected it work, it crashed instead.

What format are the video in, how long are they. What exactly was the answer you got from Apple Support?

thank you! The videos usually come as MOV recordings directly from ecamm live, but I've also had the problem with recordings I make directly in QT.
Apple said that it was surely my fault, and that I'd have to engage with them in a complete rebuild of my system, from scratch, before they'd escalate to an actual software engineer. Sigh. . They denied that others are having this problem, even though I pointed to links that made it clear that they are, but they didn't want to actually help, they just wanted me to go away.

Length of video--3 to 8 minutes. Thanks!

From what I can see, they wanted to start from a clear slate by having you reinstall macOS (which is a simple procedure) to make sure the problem is reproducible by their software engineers afterwards. Agreed that this requires some effort on your side, but without a baseline available to both you and the Apple engineer they won't have a chance to analyse the issue.
